# Make 3D plot interactive in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-3d

I use Jupyter Notebook to make analysis of datasets. There are a lot of plots in the notebook, and some of them are 3d plots.

[image]

I'm wondering if it is possible to make the 3d plot interactive, so I can later play with it in more details?

Maybe we can add a button on it? Clicking it can pop out a 3d plot and people can zoom, pan, rotate etc.

---

My thougths:

#### 1. matplotlib, %qt

This does not fit my case, because I need to continue plot after the 3d plot. `%qt` will interfere with later plots.

#### 2. mpld3

`mpld3` is almost ideal in my case, no need to rewrite anything, compatible with matplotlib. However, it only support 2D plot. And I didn't see any plan working on 3D (https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3/issues/223).

#### 3. bokeh + visjs

Didn't find any actualy example of 3d plot in `bokeh` gallery. I only find https://demo.bokeh.org/surface3d, which uses `visjs`.

#### 4. Javascript 3D plot?

Since what I need is just line and surce, is it possible to pass the data to js plot using js in the browser to make it interacive? (Then we may need to add 3d axis as well.) This may be similar to `visjs`, and `mpld3`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33440743/1204331 try: `%matplotlib notebook`

Comment: @eldad-a Just tried it, this seems good. Is it possible to mix `inline` and `notebook` in one jupyter notebook?

Comment: I'm not sure what will you miss by using only `notebook`;  just rewrote the comment as an answer to make it easier for others to find.

Comment: What was the code for producing those nice looking green colours?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I use viridis for color map

Comment: In 2021, [pyviz.org/overviews](https://pyviz.org/overviews) -> [beyond-matplotlib](https://medium.com/codex/beyond-matplotlib-and-seaborn-python-data-visualization-tools-that-work-3ef7f8d1500e) likes "Plotly is the best tool for anything 3D or interactive in Python"

Answer (score 123):

try:

`%matplotlib notebook`

see [jakevdp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2937831/jakevdp) reply 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33440743/1204331)

**EDIT for JupyterLab users:**

Follow the [instructions](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib#installation) to install [jupyter-matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib)

Then the magic command above is no longer needed, as in the example:

```
# Enabling the `widget` backend.
# This requires jupyter-matplotlib a.k.a. ipympl.
# ipympl can be install via pip or conda.
%matplotlib widget
# aka import ipympl

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 2])
plt.show()
```

Finally, note Maarten Breddels' [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44165156/1204331); IMHO [ipyvolume](https://github.com/maartenbreddels/ipyvolume) is indeed very impressive (and useful!).

Comment: Because I'm making tons of plots (see https://cdn.rawgit.com/cqcn1991/Wind-Speed-Analysis/master/output_HTML/marham.html)

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not see the issue. Have you tried to run it with `notebook`?

Comment: 1. I use both 2d and 3d plot within my notebook. How can I switch between `%matplotlib notebook` and `%matplotlib inline` 2. My notebook takes a long time to run (5 minutes). Using `%matplotlib notebook` will render images after all cell being completed, rather than after a cell is completed.

Comment: Can't really help you w/ valuable info about this (I have not played with it at this level). From the look and feel: `inline` embeds an auto-generated static png while `notebook` let you fiddle with an image a la matplotlib, till when you hit the "shutdown" button and switch to the static image. I would have searched for an auto "shutdown" command that would placed in the figs where you do not need the interactive mode. I do not know whether this is implemented at this stage.

Answer (score 33):

You may go with [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/) library. It can render interactive 3D plots directly in Jupyter Notebooks.

To do so you first need to install Plotly by running:

```
pip install plotly
```

You might also want to upgrade the library by running:

```
pip install plotly --upgrade
```

After that in you Jupyter Notebook you may write something like:

```
# Import dependencies
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Configure Plotly to be rendered inline in the notebook.
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

# Configure the trace.
trace = go.Scatter3d(
    x=[1, 2, 3],  # <-- Put your data instead
    y=[4, 5, 6],  # <-- Put your data instead
    z=[7, 8, 9],  # <-- Put your data instead
    mode='markers',
    marker={
        'size': 10,
        'opacity': 0.8,
    }
)

# Configure the layout.
layout = go.Layout(
    margin={'l': 0, 'r': 0, 'b': 0, 't': 0}
)

data = [trace]

plot_figure = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

# Render the plot.
plotly.offline.iplot(plot_figure)
```

As a result the following chart will be plotted for you in Jupyter Notebook and you'll be able to interact with it. Of course you will need to provide your specific data instead of suggeseted one.

[image]

Answer (score 24):

There is a new library called [ipyvolume](https://github.com/maartenbreddels/ipyvolume) that may do what you want, [the documentation shows live demos](https://ipyvolume.readthedocs.io). The current version doesn't do meshes and lines, but master from the git repo does (as will version 0.4). (Disclaimer: I'm the author)

Comment: nice library !  using it w voila

Answer (score 7):

[Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/) is missing in this list.
I've linked the python binding page. It definitively has animated and interative 3D Charts. And since it is Open Source most of that is available offline. Of course it is working with Jupyter

Comment: Plotly is not my favourite way to plot in any dimension, however it does deserve a place here because it is quite capable once you've figured out how to use it. I don't know why this was down voted.

And just to be clear - there IS an offline mode for Plotly where you can work with it just as you would any other plotting library. I.e. without the need to upload anything to the Plotly servers.

Answer (score 4):

A solution I came up with is to use a [vis.js](http://visjs.org/) instance in an iframe. This shows an interactive 3D plot inside a notebook, which still works in [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/). The visjs code is borrowed from the example code on the 3D graph [page](http://visjs.org/graph3d_examples.html)

A small notebook to illustrate this: [demo](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/brm/plot3d/blob/master/plot3d.ipynb)

The code itself:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
import json

def plot3D(X, Y, Z, height=600, xlabel = "X", ylabel = "Y", zlabel = "Z", initialCamera = None):

    options = {
        "width": "100%",
        "style": "surface",
        "showPerspective": True,
        "showGrid": True,
        "showShadow": False,
        "keepAspectRatio": True,
        "height": str(height) + "px"
    }

    if initialCamera:
        options["cameraPosition"] = initialCamera

    data = [ {"x": X[y,x], "y": Y[y,x], "z": Z[y,x]} for y in range(X.shape[0]) for x in range(X.shape[1]) ]
    visCode = r"""
       <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"></script>
       <div id="pos" style="top:0px;left:0px;position:absolute;"></div>
       <div id="visualization"></div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = new vis.DataSet();
        data.add(""" + json.dumps(data) + """);
        var options = """ + json.dumps(options) + """;
        var container = document.getElementById("visualization");
        var graph3d = new vis.Graph3d(container, data, options);
        graph3d.on("cameraPositionChange", function(evt)
        {
            elem = document.getElementById("pos");
            elem.innerHTML = "H: " + evt.horizontal + "<br>V: " + evt.vertical + "<br>D: " + evt.distance;
        });
       </script>
    """
    htmlCode = "<iframe srcdoc='"+visCode+"' width='100%' height='" + str(height) + "px' style='border:0;' scrolling='no'> </iframe>"
    display(HTML(htmlCode))
```

Answer (score 2):

For 3-D visualization [pythreejs](https://github.com/jovyan/pythreejs) is the best way to go probably in the notebook. It leverages the interactive widget infrastructure of the notebook, so connection between the JS and python is seamless.

A more advanced library is [bqplot](https://github.com/bloomberg/bqplot) which is a d3-based interactive viz library for the iPython notebook, but it only does 2D

Answer (score 0):

plotly's `px.scatter_3d` is the simplest solution I found for 3d plot animation after trying hard with matplotlib with no luck - you can find a good example in this post:
[Why does the size of my 3D Plotly Scatterplot randomly change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69365620/why-does-the-size-of-my-3d-plotly-scatterplot-randomly-change)