# How to change the location of all 3 axes on a 3D plot?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I am using JupyterLab to develop 3D plots. Starting out I am learning the basics of 3D plotting by plotting 3 unit vectors: x, y, and z. The default configuration is shown in Figure 1. I would like to change the location of x, y, and z axes to match the plot in Figure 2 and Figure 3.

[image: MatPlotLib]

I can use `ax.view_init(elevation, azimuth)` to change to change the view of the graph, but I would prefer not to do that.

I am failing to find a simple solution to this issue. How can I make this transformation?

Comment: is this a Matlab question?

Comment: This is not a MATLAB question. You might find your answer here: [Displaying rotatable 3D plots in IPython or Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33436221/3460361). By the way, when you write "_I can use_ `ax.view_init(elevation, azimuth)` _to change to change the view of the graph, but I would prefer not to do that._" You should explain why you do not want to implement a solution that works, or at least why it is not doing what you are after ...

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, you just have to set `view` to the correct angle, in this case, `view(135,35)` , for example,

```
% Set the limits of the plot
axis equal;
xlim([0, 2]);     ylim([0, 2]);     zlim([0, 2]);

% Label the axes
xlabel('x');  ylabel('y');  zlabel('z');

view(135,35)

% Turn the grid on
grid on;
```

[image]